# What is the expected value for a die game where you get to throw the die 4 times and recieve prizes?

Tags: probability, expected-value

There is a fair die with 4 sides ( 1 , 2 ,3, 4 ). A player is allowed to roll it 3 times. If the player rolls a 4 once they get 2 dollars, if they roll a 4 twice they get 3 dollars and if they roll a 4 three times they get 5 dollars, what is the expected value of a game?

I approached it like this:

> Value of rolling 1 four is : 2 and probability is $\frac14$.
>
>  Value of rolling 2 fours is : 3 and probability is $\frac14$.
>
>  Value of rolling 3 fours is : 5 and probability is $\frac14$.
>
>  Therefore $E(X)$ for 1 game is $$2\times \frac14 + 3\times \left(\frac14\right)^2 + 5\times\left(\frac14\right)^3$$
>
> Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities are wrong.  $P_n=P(X=n)$.  $P_1=3\times \frac{1}{4}\times(\frac{3}{4})^2=0.421875$, $P_2=3\times \frac{3}{4}\times(\frac{1}{4})^2=0.140625$, $P_3=(\frac{1}{4})^3=0.015625$.

Your $E(X)$ approach is correct.  You have to use the correct probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, while calculating the probability of rolling $4$ exactly $k$ times, you have to

1. **Ensure that a $4$ is not rolled in any of the remaining $3-k$  rolls.**
2. **Take into account that $441$ and $414$ count as distinct outcomes. That is you need to be careful about the order in which the $4$'s are rolled.**